# 403 Error with PHP cURL from external website

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, user-agent, php-curl

I am trying to get string from external website but i am getting 403 error. I have tried using custom user agent and same error. Can you please check and help me to get it fixed.

Code :

```
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);    

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
$homepage = file_get_contents_curl("https://www.transunion.com/");
echo $homepage;
```

Help me fix this.

Comment: Look in your browser's Developer Tools when you're visiting the site. Make a note of what it sends, and try to copy it via the cURL code. If it's easier, try to emulate the request in PostMan and then let PostMan generate the cURL/PHP code for you automatically. (N.B. Another possible for reason for this could be if you made too many requests and your IP is blocked or something like that.)

Comment: @ADyson your information is not clear. Which tab in developer tool i have to look and which code i have to copy and past in PostMan and mainly what wrong with my current code and how can i fix it.?

Comment: $agent is in the global scope so in the code as written above `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);` will set the user agent to an empty string. "PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $agent in test.php on line 13". Also, when I take and run this code it works and returns the home page with a 200. So the 403 is probably bot detection and not something wrong with your code.

Comment: `Which tab in developer tool i have to look`...since we're talking about a HTTP request, then you should be looking in the Network tab, since that deals with all network requests going from the browser. Sorry I assumed it would be obvious to anyone who has dealt with website development before.

Comment: `hich code i have to copy and past in PostMan`...I didn't say to copy and paste anything in PostMan, I said to look at the features of the HTTP request the browser is generating, and  then you need to set the relevant settings in PostMan to make it generate exactly the same request with all the same features. This requires you to understand the basics of a HTTP request (e.g. headers, body, method etc). Once you've got it working in PostMan, PostMan has a feature which can auto-generate equivalent PHP/cURL code for the request you created, which you can then copy/paste into your PHP application

Comment: But...drew010 is likely correct - your cURL code is simply not passing the user agent because you didn't take careful note of the structure of the PHP code you wrote, and/or possible don't understand enough about how [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) works in PHP.

Comment: @drew010 are you getting result with 200 response? can you please paste the code in answer box where you get success.

Comment: @ADyson i checked with network tab and i am using the same 200 OK response code URL with cURL but still i have a error 403 instead of getting string.

Comment: I copied your code 100% as is (added <?php to the beginning of course) and ran that. I got the warning about $agent being undefined, but the 200 response with their home page was returned to me, not a 403.

Comment: Did you move the `$agent= ...` line inside the function yet and retry it?